# Rails Model.reset_column_information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have

`Product` model with

```
belongs_to :detail, counter_cache: true
```

my migration

`add_column :details, :products_count, :integer, default: 0`

and want to reset it`(products_count)` with

```
Detail.reset_column_information
```

but after it my object still has `products_count=>20`

So my  questions are

1.how to reset properly `products_count` when i delete related product's obj?

2.Why it `reset_column_information` did't do it?

or i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

To reset the counters use [reset_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters).
For example:

```
Detail.reset_counters({id}, :products)
```

Make sure you supply the appropriate detail id{id} for which you want to reset the products_count.

`reset_column_information` is used to reset all the schema cached information about columns. It is not used for resetting counters.